# geodesic distance on 3d triangular mesh using scikit-fmm or gdist

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, mesh

I'm trying to evaluate a geodesic distance matrix on the TOSCA dataset.
e.g. the following 3d mesh-
[image]

I've tried using two python implementations.

1. The first one is the [scikit-fmm](https://github.com/scikit-fmm/scikit-fmm), which does not seems to work on 3d structures at all (am I right?) hence not suitable to the task.
2. The other one is the [gdist](https://github.com/the-virtual-brain/tvb-geodesic) package, which Unfortunatlly works on the toy example they provide, but does not work on my mesh, which is only 10,000 faces and 5000 vertices.
   When using the gdist library I have the following error:

   ```
   Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
   --------CODE SNIPPET----------
   c = sio.loadmat('raw_data/TOSCA/cat0.mat')
   c = c['surface'][0][0]
   X = c[0]
   Y = c[1]
   Z = c[2]
   TRIV = c[3].astype(np.int32)
   vertices = np.array(zip(X, Y, Z)).astype(np.float64)
   vertices = np.reshape(vertices, (vertices.shape[0], 3))
   src = np.array([1], dtype=np.int32)
   trg = np.array([2], dtype=np.int32)

   np.random.shuffle(TRIV)

   a = gdist.compute_gdist(vertices,TRIV[:5000], source_indices = src, target_indices = trg)
   ```

Is there another solution? Am I using gdist or scikit-fmm the wrong way?

Comment: In my experiences, I've only encountered SIGSEGV when I try to use too much RAM. Can you split up the task at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no, both because "hiding" more faces would make the answer irrelevant, and because mesh with 5000 faces is considered small, I know that those computations can be much bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to use [MeshLib](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshLib#python-integration) library with python interface. After installation via `pip`:

```
import meshlib.mrmeshpy as mr
```

Load a mesh from TOSCA dataset in OFF format:

```
mesh = mr.loadMesh("centaur1.off")
```

I found the meshes from this dataset here: https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/partial

Then you will be interested in two function as follows.

1. `mr.computeSurfaceDistances(mesh, surfacePoint)`, which returns the distance from given surface point to every vertex in the mesh computed by [Fast Marching method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_marching_method). For example, here are computed distances are visualized by color and isolines:

[image: Isolines of distances computed in MeshLib]

2. `mr.computeGeodesicPath(mesh, surfacePoint1, surfacePoint2)`, which computes exact geodesic path between two surface points. The computation starts from a path approximation given by Dijkstra or Fast Marching method and then it is iteratively reduced in length until convergence. Geodesic path example between two points:

[image: Geodesic path in MeshLib]